# How to put a css div box directly under another css div box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the 'usernamevalidation' div directly under the 'usernamealert' div.

```css
.usernamealert {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 60px;
  width: 20%;
}

.usernamevalidation {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="usernamealert">
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:Red; font-size:28px;">ALERT</p>
</div>
<div class="usernamevalidation">
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:28px;">Username should contain:
  </p>
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:24px;">- At least 5 characters
  </p>
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:24px;">- Letters and integers only</p>
</div>
```

It is meant to look something on the lines of this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSNTx.jpg)

Comment: How is it currently displaying? What have you already tried?

Comment: Currently, there is a like a small space between the alert box and the other box.

Comment: Why are you using two separate divs? To me your image looks like a single div with text laid out inside it.

Comment: `p {
margin: 0;
}
`

Comment: @RobinZigmond That is what its meant to look like. I cant use a single div because you can't have 2 different colours of text in 1 div box.

Comment: @Rolls_Reus_0wner whyever not? Just use different elements within it. You might even put 2 (or more) separate divs inside the containing div (although I would expect it to be possible with just elements like <p> and <h2> or whatever), but you need a containing div so that you can control its shape. (When I say "need" - you can probably do it without, but this is surely the most natural way.)

Answer (score 1):

Each `<p>` element has by default some margin on the top. The first `<p>` of your second div is the one creating that gap.

```
.usernamealert {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 60px;
  width: 20%;
}

.usernamevalidation {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
  width: 30%;
}

<div class="usernamealert">
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:Red; font-size:28px;">ALERT</p>
</div>
<div class="usernamevalidation">
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:28px; margin-top:0">Username should contain:
  </p>
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:24px;">- At least 5 characters
  </p>
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:24px;">- Letters and integers only</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions you can use to solve your problem.
Here's my:

> https://jsfiddle.net/y0mxq4gn/

I just wrapped your `div`s in another `div`, which acts as a container.
This container is a "flexbox". Have a look here:

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

These are really powerful, expecially when creating "sort of layouts". I have just put this "flexbox" and make its children follow vertical flow. By default, no spacing appear between elements, unless you set them via CSS in most cases.

Comment: Ok it works but, the 'usernamealert' box joins the div box above it!

Comment: You have said "put a css div box directly under another css div box". No margin, nor padding was stated. You can try giving a `margin-top` to the second `div`, then set the `background-color` of the "container div" the same gray color of your images.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top margin from the first paragraph tag on the `.usernamevalidation` div:

```css
.usernamealert {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 60px;
  width: 20%;
}

.usernamevalidation {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
  width: 30%;
}
.usernamevalidation p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="usernamealert">
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:Red; font-size:28px;">ALERT</p>
</div>
<div class="usernamevalidation">
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:28px;">Username should contain:
  </p>
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:24px;">- At least 5 characters
  </p>
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:24px;">- Letters and integers only</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `display:flow-root;` in the .usernamevalidation and it will do the trick as you could see below.

```css
.usernamealert {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 60px;
  width: 80%;
}

.usernamevalidation {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  display:flow-root;
  height: 150px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="usernamealert">
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:Red; font-size:28px;">ALERT</p>
</div>
<div class="usernamevalidation">
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:28px;">Username should contain:
  </p>
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:24px;">- At least 5 characters
  </p>
  <p style="font-family:Impact; color:White; font-size:24px;">- Letters and integers only</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style `p` as you wish and set styles for different paragraphs. Yet inline css is not good coding style - it makes you to repeat similar code many times and your html-file becomes too big and messed.

```css
p {
  font-family:Impact;
  color: white;
  font-size:28px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
p.alert {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
p.list {
  text-indent: 30pt;
  margin: 0;
}
p.list:before {
  content: "- ";
}
.usernamealert {
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="usernamealert">
  <p class="alert">ALERT</p>
  <p>Username should contain:</p>
  <p class="list">At least 5 characters</p>
  <p class="list">Letters and integers only</p>
</div>
```